# Timers keep jumping ahead of time

Tags: java, android, android-studio, timer

I implemented 2 updateTimerThreads that were like this:

```
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

            secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;
            milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
            //Log.d(TAG, "Secs: " + secs + " Min: " +  mins);
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }
    };
```

**2 Starting methods:**

```
public void startTimer(){
        if(firsttime){
            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
            firsttime = false;
        }
    }
```

and 2 Pausing methods:

```
public void pauseTimer(){
        timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
        customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
        firsttime = true;
    }
```

**My Problem:**

Whenever I switch between one timer and the other (pause one, start the other), they keep adding a lot of time, minute's worth in seconds.

Any ideas of how to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain to me what this does, according to you? `timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;`

Comment: The very statement I have 2 THREADS!! Tells ur in a world of trouble. Try to find all variables shared between these 2 timers and synchronize them ASAP or post more code relevant to your problem

Comment: @RVISHAL The only common thing that I know of is the "SystemClock.uptimeMillis()", not much that's relevant to the issue in the code

Comment: @MaartenBodewes It saves the current time that the timer was paused at, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: If you're displaying these in views or creating a stopwatch functionality, you could try looking into a [Chronometer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer)

Comment: @SammyT I'm running the timer in a service class, as I want it to be able to run in the background.
I'm not sure if you can implement a Chronometer in the service class, also, the Chronometer doesn't hold/save current values, and I need those.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You might be getting duplicates running at the same time. Try putting an additional `.removeCallbacks();` at the top of your `run()` method.

Comment: @SammyT No luck..
Could it be that I'm using the System.uptimeMillis() for both timers?
Is this the standard reference when making a CountUp timer?

Comment: I'm not certain but I don't think `uptimeMillis()` should cause an issue unless your device is going to sleep. Personally, I would switch the `postDelayed()` inside of `run()` to delay 1000 milliseconds and log out all variables within it including the `uptimeMillis()`.